# Проверить, сколько раз заданный символ входит в заданный текст

Tags: c#, строки

Необходимо проверить, сколько раз заданный символ входит в заданный текст, и подсчитать количество символов в строке.

Comment: а ты что-то пробовал? покажи как ты пытался решить эту задачу, какие методы использовал, что не получилось? если не пробовал то сначала попробуй, потом добавь свою попытку в вопрос

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Количество символов:

```
int Count(string p, char ch){
    int c = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++){
        if(p[i] == ch) c++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Длина:

```
string b = "lll";
int len = b.Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Чуть более короткий по записи вариант:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var line = "HelloWorld";
    var charCount = CountByCharacter(line, 'o'); //2
    var length = line.Length; //10
}

static int CountByCharacter(string word, char character) =>
    word.Count(x => x.Equals(character));
```